# regular expression to solve for the following

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Example 1

`asdk[wovkd'vk'psacx`**u5=205478499|205477661**`zamd;amd;a;d`

Example 2

`sadlmdlmdadsld`**u5=205478499|205477661|234567899**`amsd/samdamd`

u5 can have multiple values separated by `|`

How can I capture all u5 values from a long string I have?

Comment: What language? What have you tried? Please format your question in the future.

Comment: I am using big query substr(Data,length(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Other_Data, r'(?i)(.*?)u5=...'))+4,9) - This picks up just the first one

Comment: @chris85 - i am using Google Bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, "asdk[wovkd'vk'psacxu5=205478499|205477661zamd;amd;a;d" AS junk UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "sadlmdlmdadsldu5=205478499|205477661|234567899amsd/samdamd"
)
SELECT id, SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(junk, r'(?i)u5=([\d|]*)'), '|') AS value
FROM data
```

with output as below

```sql
id  value    
1   205478499    
    205477661    
2   205478499    
    205477661    
    234567899
```